# Wikidata import into virtuoso

Tags: sparql, wikidata, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I would like to load wikidata into virtuoso. After days of searching I was unable to find any tutorial or at least somebody that uses virtuoso to sparql query wikidata. I would not like to spend money on a server to load 50G+ data for nothing.
Why virtuoso and not blazegraph for instance? Because I'm used to use virtuoso for DBpedia.

Comment: You load Wikidata as any other RDF dataset into Virtuoso. Or what exactly is the question here? I mean, how to load data is clearly in the Virtuoso docs: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader - or do you have any other question?

Comment: Actually, I am suffering with this now, since I am trying to load `latest-truthy.nt.bz2` and I am getting this error:
`File latest-truthy.nt error 42000 RDFGE: RDF box with a geometry RDF type and a non-geometry content`
I think I will create a separate question for it

Comment: This repo may be a good start: https://github.com/patrickhoefler/wikidata-virtuoso

Comment: The repo noted above by @MohamedGad-Elrab is LONG outdated. I suggest you follow up to [this related issue on the Virtuoso project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/295), or [create your own new issue there](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/). You could also post to the [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, here's a guide that covers the creation and deployment of a Wikidata instance using Virtuoso.

- [Loading Wikidata's dataset into a Virtuoso Instance](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/loading-wikidata-into-virtuoso-open-source-or-enterprise-edition/2717)
- [Live SPARQL Query Results Example](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2F&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs1%20%3Fs2%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs1%20%3Fs1textp%20%3Fo1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fo1%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%27%22China%22%27%20%20option%20%28score%20%3Fsc%29%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs1%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%3E%20%3Fs2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs3%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2FP66%3E%20%3Fs1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3Fs2%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=30000000&signal_void=on)
- [Live Wikidata SPARQL Query Service deployed using Virtuoso](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql)
- [Live Free Text & Faceted Search Example](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/fct/facet.vsp?qxml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20%3F%3E%3Cquery%20inference%3D%22%22%20invfp%3D%22IFP_OFF%22%20same-as%3D%22SAME_AS_OFF%22%20view3%3D%22%22%20s-term%3D%22e%22%20c-term%3D%22type%22%20agg%3D%22%22%20limit%3D%2250%22%3E%3Ctext%3EChina%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Cclass%20iri%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FAdministrativeArea%22%20%2F%3E%3Cview%20type%3D%22text-d%22%20limit%3D%2250%22%20offset%3D%220%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fquery%3E&timeout=16000)
- [Live Wikidata Faceted Search & Browsing Service deployed using Virtuoso](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/fct)

Comment: What would be the minimum memory footprint for this? The example instructions have 386GB which is a bit stiff.

Comment: And what are the details of the procedure?

Answer (score -3):

As indicated here and elsewhere, loading Wikidata into Virtuoso should simply be a matter of creating the turtle file (better is to have multiple turtle files) from the download and bulk loading it in.   To get decent performance, a number of parameters have to be changed in virtuoso.ini.

There is a problem loading Wikidata into Virtuoso, however, due to a long-standing bug in Virtuoso having to do with its implementation of geo-coordinates.  To get around this requires patching Virtuoso, and is not for the faint of heart.

Here are the instructions on what do to get the open-source version of Virtuoso to load Wikidata.  Note that the patching of the geo-coordinate code might cause problems using the resultant KB.

1/ Patch the geo-coordinate literal code, editing virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Wi/rdfbox.c to comment out two pieces of code that check for non-terrestrial coordinates.  Note that this is a *bug* in Virtuoso and that Wikidata conforms to the specification of this datatype.

> /*non-terrestrial cooordinates  if (RDF_BOX_GEO_TYPE == type && DV_GEO != box_dtp && DV_LONG_INT != box_dtp)
>      sqlr_new_error ("42000",  "RDFGE",  "RDF box with a geometry RDF type and a non-geometry content"); */
>
> /*non-terrestrial cooordinates if (type == RDF_BOX_GEO && box_dtp != DV_GEO)
>       sqlr_new_error ("22023", "SR559", "The RDF box of type geometry needs a spatial object as a value, not a value of type %s (%d)", dv_type_title (box_dtp), box_dtp); */

2/  Patch the Turtle loader, editing the end of rdf_rl_lang_id in virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Wi/ttlpv.sql to look as follows.  Note that this is another *bug* in Virtuoso that is triggered by parallel loading of langstrings with different languages.

> id:= sequence_next ('RDF_LANGUAGE_TWOBYTE', 1, 1);
>   --pfps  insert into rdf_language (rl_twobyte, rl_id) values (id, ln);
>    insert soft rdf_language (rl_twobyte, rl_id) values (id, ln);
>    commit work; -- if load non transactional, this is still a sharpp transaction boundary.
>    log_enable (old_mode, 1);
>   --pfps get the actual id, as it may be different
>    id := (select RL_TWOBYTE from DB.DBA.RDF_LANGUAGE where RL_ID = ln);
>    rdf_cache_id ('l', ln, id);
>    return id;

Comment: Could you please be more specific in how it can be made working?

Comment: Note that the speed of loading Wikidata into Virtuoso is much improved if you split the Wikidata dump into multiple (ideally hundreds) of pieces.   This also is not trivial.

Comment: Also, if you are loading the complete dump (with over 10 billion triples) you need a machine with at least 256GB of main memory (maybe even at least 512GB) and an SSD to store the DB.   A machine with less memory will start thrashing part way through the load and progress will be *very* slow thereafter.

Comment: http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Get_your_own_copy_of_WikiData#Test_with_Apache_Jena shows the current try with a different SPARQL store. I'll test blazegraph and virtuoso after that again. The official blazegraph import also splits the triples. Still I'd appreciate to get a detailed documentation of the process to be included in the wiki mentioned above.